# How to move a GameObject with the camera when picked up in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a newbie in Unity. I have searched on the internet for tutorials on how to pick up GameObjects and followed them as it is. But here's the problem:
[This here is when I set the Camera as a parent to GameObject, initially....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH4Xq.png)

[And here's what happens when I move the camera.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqUe5.png)

The problem here is that the Object doesn't stay on the crosshair

This happens only when moving the camera along the Up-and-Down Axis (not sure if x or y).

However, this doesn't seem to be a problem in any tutorials. Is there any part of the code missing?

P.S:- I have set the Camera as a parent to the GameObject in the hierarchy directly without any code.

Comment: Try setting gameobject as parent of camera

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know the exact problem without at least a video of it, but the first thing here is to make sure there's nothing messing with the object's transform outside of camera's parenting.

Comment: There are no scripts messing the object's transform